# Crop image using a bounding box react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, crop, react-native-camera

i have a camera view in my app in which there is a resizable bounding box
[image: camera view bounding box image]

now after taking the image i want to able to only take the part of the image that was focused so i used ImageEditor from [this react-native library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/image-editor)

the issue i have i am not getting consistent results on the cropping i currently have th following values
`boxX` staring X position of the bounding box; `boxY` staring Y position of the bounding box; `boxWidth` width of the bounding box; `boxHeight` height of the bounding box.

i used the following code at first

```
ImageEditor.cropImage(image.uri, 
                {
                    offset: {x: boxX, y: boxY},
                    size: {width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight},
                }
            )
```

this gives a very pixalated and very wrong cropping of the image i dont know why, then i added some calculations to it by adding new variables like the image width and height and also the devices width and height and came up with this code:

```
ImageEditor.cropImage(data.uri, 
                {
                    offset: {x: ((boxX)/deviceWidth)*data.width, y:((boxY)/deviceHeight)*data.height},
                    size: {width: boxWidth/deviceWidth*imageWidth, height: boxHeight/deviceHeight*imageHeight},

                }
            )
```

this is much better but the cropping is still wrong on Android but on iOS this seems to work fine and accurate, my question is how can i achieve this please let me know if there is any calculations i should do to get consistent results.

Answer (score 4):

**For image cropping I think you should try:**

**1) https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker**

It is more used, looks to be maintained better and could simplify your work.

**or**

**2) a picker and https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor**

if you want more complicated editing.

**or**

**3)** if you are satisfied with your current library for iOS, use one of the 2 from above only for android.

**Note:** this is a known issue of the react-native-image-editor, especially for android. The discussions and possible workarounds that could work on some devices can be found here:

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-image-editor/issues/54#issuecomment-754688978

Comment: yes but i don't want there to be another screen for editing

Comment: the user already selects which part of the image they want using the bounding box and it should be cropped with that width and height without opening another editor

Comment: I updated my answer with an additional note.

Comment: Yes those values are actually correct offset X,Y, and Width and Height are correct, while debugging this I created an overlay View and assigned these values as the position and width/height for that View so i can see the View change width/height and x/y in realtime as the user resizes the box and those values are correct

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? if yes, what appraoch did you use?